# Between SQL ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I recived Task:

Add a method to the Profile class, called get all profiles, which:

• accepts a min and max for the birth year

• issues a BETWEEN SQL clause in a where clause to locate Profiles with birth years that are between min

year and max year

• defends itself against SQL injection when applying the parameters to the SQL clauses

• returns a collection of Profiles in ASC birth year order

Profile Class:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :user

     validates :first_name, presence: true
     validates :last_name, presence: true

    validates :gender, inclusion: %w(male female)

    validate :first_and_last
    validate :male_Sue


    def first_and_last
      if (first_name.nil? and last_name.nil?)
        errors.add(:base, "Specify a first or a last.")
      end
    end

    def male_Sue
      if (first_name == "Sue" and gender == "male")
        errors.add(:base, "we are prevent male by name Sue.")
      end
    end

    def get_all_profiles

    end
  end
```

How can complete this task? explanation appriciating...

I should pass this rspec test:

```
context "rq14" do
         context "Profile has a get_all_profiles method" do
           subject(:profile) { Profile.new }
           it { is_expected.to respond_to(:get_all_profiles) }
         end
         it "will return a list of profiles between requested birth years in ascending order" do
           user = User.create(:username=>"testUser", :password_digest=>"xxxx")
           startYear = 1960
           endYear = 2000
           testYear = 1985
           testCount = 0
           (0..20).each do |i|
             birthYear = startYear + rand(0..(endYear - startYear))
             if (birthYear <= testYear)
               testCount = testCount + 1
             end
             profile = Profile.create(:user_id=>user.id, :gender=>"male", :birth_year=>birthYear, :first_name=>"User #{i}", :last_name=>"Smith#{i}")
           end
           profileGroup = Profile.new.get_all_profiles(startYear, testYear)
           expect(profileGroup.length).to be(testCount)
           # test that results are sorted by birthyear and are ascending
           year = startYear
           profileGroup.each do |t|
             expect(t.birth_year).to be >= year
             year = t.birth_year
           end
         end
       end
     end
```

Thanks, Michael.

Comment: Some more details will help. What are the parameters? dates? years? Does the model hold a birth date? year?

Answer (score 1):

It's the answer:

```
def get_all_profiles(start_year, end_year)
   Profile.where(:birth_year => start_year..end_year).order(:birth_year )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's more Rails style to use a scope:

```
scope :all_profiles -> (date_from, date_to) { where birth_date: date_from..date_to }
```